# MS WebPI package runCommand not working in Manifest.xml

Tags: iis, webmatrix, msdeploy, web-platform-installer

How do I get the [runCommand provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to work in the `Manifest.xml`
of a MS Deploy package when installed via the Web Platform Installer?

I'm trying to build a simple test MS Web Deploy package installable by
the Web Platform Installer via a [custom feed](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-applications.aspx).  I'm trying to use
the `runCommand` provider in the [Manifest.xml](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi/blob/05d68464d8fdc360387b9976984b74dd4e0d6827/sample.msdeploy/Manifest.xml) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<msDeploy.iisApp>
  <iisApp path="IISWSGISampleApp" />
  <runCommand path="set" />
</msDeploy.iisApp>
```

The `set` is used just to output the environment the command is run
under, but it doesn't work for any number of different `path`
values.  When I install the package via the Web Platform Installer with any `path` attribute
I get the same error:

```
[13:54:312]Source runCommand (set) does not match destination (set) differing in attributes (isSource). Update pending.
[13:54:315]Updating runCommand (set).
    Details:
    operationType: Update
    providerName: runCommand
    path: set
EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '\\?\C:\Users\rpatterson\Documents\My Web Sites\IISWSGISampleApp'.
File name: '\\?\C:\Users\rpatterson\Documents\My Web Sites\IISWSGISampleApp'
...
```

It installs just fine if I remove the `<runCommand>` element from the `Manifest.xml`.  I have also confirmed that the `C:\Users\rpatterson\Documents\My Web Sites\IISWSGISampleApp` does exist when WebPI shows the error.  Also, I found out that the `\\?\` style paths are for [safely referencing long paths in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath), so it may be that some part of long path support is broken.

I'm doing all this under Windows 7 Professional, Web Platform
Installer 4.0, and Web Matrix 2.0 RC whose about dialog says:

```
Version 2.0 RC
WebMatrix: 7.1.1587.0
IIS Express: 8.0.8298.0
.NET Framework: 4.0.30319.17379 built by: FXBETAREL
Web Deploy: 7.1.1516.0
SQL Server Compact: 4.0.8854.1
Web Platform Installer: 7.1.1586.1
ASP.NET Web Pages: 2.0.20505.0
ASP.NET Web Pages: 1.0.20105.407
```

The code behind all this is in [IISWSGI on GitHub](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi), [use this commit](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi/commit/05d68464d8fdc360387b9976984b74dd4e0d6827) to test.  To reproduce the
environment I'm using, see the [IISWSGI documentation](https://github.com/rpatterson/iiswsgi#sample-package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was once able to use `runCommand` without error after having been able to reproduce the error having done nothing but some combination machine reboot and using WebPI to install the app in between.  After further testing, I can now reproduce the error by:

- reboot the machine
- use WebPI to install the app
- exit WebPI
- use WebPI to install the app again (without rebooting)

Then if I reboot the machine I can use WebPI to install the app again.  IOW, it appears that WebPI has a bug where it can't be launched twice without rebooting the machine.

Comment: I just tried to do this again and did updates in a different order and I can't reproduce the problem.  IOW `runCommand` still works.  So it may be something about the order of applying the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `set` command into a `.bat` / `.cmd` and referencing that as the path for `runCommand`. [As long as you pass no arguments to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672893/pass-parameters-to-batch-file-in-msdeploy-runcommand), it will be included in the package and run when you sync the package elsewhere.