# WebDeploy different parts of one project to multiple websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7.5, webdeploy

Given an ASP.NET webapp that is already deployed using WebDeploy to its live server, how can I also deploy a subset of that application to another server?

eg

- Entire webapp / all files including static files-> web deploy to domain.com
- Static files only (js,images,css) -> web deploy to static.com

This is for the purpose of creating a separate cookieless site for static content only.

Is it possible with just one publish profile? Or do I need to create two publish profiles?

And is it even possible to create a publish profile that only deploys the static part of the webapp (everything in the ~/Content directory)?

Both target servers are II7.5 running on Windows 2008 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with two publish profiles. It would involve skipping ([with caveats if performing the deployment from within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576662/msdeploy-skip-rules-when-using-msbuild-publishprofile-with-visual-studio-2012)) the appropriate content for each profile.

However, I'd recommend doing a full deploy to your application server and then using the `runCommand` provider to execute a batch file.

To do this, you could define the following in your publish profile:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
        $(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest);
        AddContentDeploymentToSourceManifest;
    </AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AddContentDeploymentToSourceManifest">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="runCommand">
            <Path>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\deployContent.bat</Path>
        </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Then, in deployContent.bat:

```
REM Detect MSDeploy location (stolen from VS generated CMD)
if "%MSDeployPath%" == "" (
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%h  in (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy" /s  ^| findstr -i "InstallPath"`) do (
if /I "%%h" == "InstallPath" ( 
if /I "%%i" == "REG_SZ" ( 
if not "%%j" == "" ( 
if "%%~dpj" == "%%j" ( 
set MSDeployPath=%%j
))))))

"%MSDeployPath%mdeploy.exe" -verb:sync ^
    -source:iisApp="application site name" 
    -dest:iisApp="static content site name",computerName=http://contentserver:8192/msdeploy.axd
    -skip:File=^.*(?<!png|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$
```

... which deploys the site from the application server to the content server, skipping anything that does not have one of the predefined list of static content extensions.

(FYI: [Don't try to sent arguments to your batch file unless it already exists on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672893/pass-parameters-to-batch-file-in-msdeploy-runcommand))