# How to work with MSDeploy through command line?

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I want to run a .bat file on my server via MSDeploy from remote. I installed the remote agent service on the server and started it. Also installed MSdeploy on my computer.

Now I want to execute the bat file from remote.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks, any help will be upvoted immediately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `runCommand` provider:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync ^
              -source:runCommand="path\to\batch.bat" ^
              -dest:auto,computerName=serverName,userName=user,password=pass
```

This will automatically transfer the batch file to the remote server as long as it is named `.bat` or `.cmd` and [you do not pass any parameters to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672893/pass-parameters-to-batch-file-in-msdeploy-runcommand).

Comment: thank you! but now i receive an error : could not complete the request to remote agent URL .....error : the name = expires part of the cookie is invalid.    -  Do you have an idea?

Comment: my destination computer has 2 names one Computer Name and one Full   Computer Name. Hmm

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to execute the bat file on one machine from another machine? If so have you considered PsExec from Sysinternals? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Comment: sorry, I want to make this happen with MSDeploy

Comment: Was just making a suggestion.